# execv error when using a toolchain

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm getting this error when I try to compile a small helloworld c file:

```
/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -DARCH_ARM -o hello.c.o -c hello.c
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error trying to exec '/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-4.4.0_ARMv5TE/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.0/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/as': execv: No such file or directory
```

I am running ubuntu 14.04 lts ... I see that I have exec command but there is no execv on my ubuntu. what is execv ?

Thanks

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv

Comment: Hi Mike, the error complains it doesn't find the execv file not the execv() function. Is it possible that the toolchain is for an older ubuntu version ?

Comment: The error is complaining about GCC not being able to `exec()`ute the assembler (`as`) not an `exec` call in your source code.  It seems you have a broken installation of GCC or did not set up the environment appropriately.  But it's close to impossible to tell for sure with so little information.

Comment: I made it to work on Ubuntu 12.04 after installing zip unzip git g++ ccache cmake make autoconf2.13 yasm      gcc-multilib g++-multilib ia32-libs .

On Ubuntu 14.04 there is no ia32-libs and I get the same error as before. 
Do you know what is the corresponding ia32-libs for Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by missing 32 bit libraries from my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

To solve this I had to install:

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386

sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6